# Facebook social plugin with react.lazy not loading consistently

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using the [Facebook Social Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/) and since adding `React.lazy()` the `FacebookFeed` component isn't *always* loading and displaying the feed properly. `forceUpdate()` was my first possible solution, but it should not be used anymore, so I'm stuck.

Is the best solution for this to essentially `reload` that component after scrolling the page (i.e 50px)? I'm not sure how to do that without using `componentDidMount()`, which is also not to be used anymore. Does anyone have a solution for this issue?

index.html:

```
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v7.0"></script>
</body>
```

About.js:

```
function About() {
  return (
    <div>
      // other content
      <FacebookFeed />
    </div>
  )
}
```

FacebookFeed.js:

```
class FacebookFeed extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/{page-name}">
        // blockquote per FB
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: If you adding a new tag that Facebook need to know about you should use FB.XFBML.parse https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/

Comment: Using `window.FB.XFBML.parse();` seems to work fine on Chrome and Safari, but I get "window.FB is undefined" on Firefox.

Comment: Guessing you are calling it before the FB SDK have loaded

Comment: In the HTML file, I have the `#fb-root` and SDK `<script>` before the `#root`, so it should be loading first (or at least I think it should be)

Comment: You have async defer on the script so it will load in parallel with the page. It has to finish loading before window.FB is available

Comment: Seems to be working now! If you'd like, you can move this into an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks so much!